# Varient data type changes value 0 to empty or blank

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am passing value 0 in the below code

```
Dim searchtext As Varient

Public Sub xyz_page_load()
    searchtext = 0
If searchtext = "" Or searchtext = Empty Then
   Debug.Print "Error" 'this line should not execute.
Else
    Debug.Print "Good"
End If
End Sub
```

It should not go in "Error" line of code.
Can anyone make me know why it is happening so?
Why varient data type is considering 0 as empty or blank?

Comment: `As Varient` --> `As Variant` is it your real code? it works for me as expected

Comment: No No Sorry there will not be "" with 0. it will be searchtext = 0

Comment: if it's your real code, it can't be even compile, because `As Varient` should be `As Variant`

Comment: Sorry @simoco I am changing the code. it should be searchtext = 0.

Comment: for searchtext = "0", it is also working fine for me but not with searchtext = 0. Can you please tell me why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Empty` equals to default value *of compared type*.

Say for `Integer` type `Empty` would be `0`:

```
MsgBox 0 = Empty ' returns True
MsgBox CInt(Empty) ' returns 0
```

for `String` type `Empty` would be empty string `""`:

```
MsgBox "" = Empty ' returns True
MsgBox CStr(Empty) ' returns ""
```

for `Boolean` type `Empty` would be `False`:

```
MsgBox False = Empty ' returns True
MsgBox CBool(Empty) ' returns False
```

Since you're using `Dim searchtext As Variant`, variable `searchtext` can store values of any type, but when you assign `0` to a variable: `searchtext = 0`, type becames `Variant / Integer`:

[image]

and `Empty` for this type is `0`. That's why `searchtext = Empty` evaluates to `True` for `searchtext = 0`

Comment: Thank you so much @simoco. You made complicated problem easy. :)